# Cat filename not working

Tags: cat

I've redirected topas output to a file in AIX 6.1, but the file is not readable using `cat`:

```
$ cat a.txt

$
```

While using `pg` it shows perfect output:

```
Topas Monitor for host:    jsitrs0058  Interval:   5    Tue Oct  4 18:08:40 2016
                                    DATA  TEXT  PAGE                  PGFAULTS
USER          PID     PPID PRI  NI   RES   RES SPACE    TIME  CPU%   I/O   OTH COMMAND
root      1966214        1  60  20   145     2   145  128:04   0.0    11   417 syncd
root            1        0  60  20   204    11   204   91:05   0.0   253 74447298 init
oracle    8651002        1  60  20  2532 21781  2532   25:54   0.0     0  2640 oracle
........................................
```

vi a.txt

```
USER^[[15GPID^[[23GPPID PRI  NI   RES   RES SPACE    TIME  CPU%   I/O   OTH COMMAND^[[58G
root^[[11G1966214^[[26G1  60  20   145^[[46G2   145  128:04   0.0    11   417 syncd
root^[[17G1^[[26G0  60  20   204    11   204   91:05   0.0   253 74447298 init
oracle    8651002^[[26G1  60  20  2532 21781  2532   25:54   0.0^[[72G0  2640 oracle
 ......................
```

I need to get similar output like `pg <filename>` for `cat <filename>`?

Comment: What does `ls -l a.txt` show?  How about `file a.txt`?

Comment: Well, it's a safe bet that the file is a few hundred bytes long — with cursor-positioning escape sequences in it.  Although the fact that `cat a.txt` displays *nothing at all* is puzzling.  I'd be more interested in seeing the output from `cat -A a.txt` and `cat -v a.txt`.

Answer (score 2):

The escape sequences mess up the output from cat. Try `cat -v a.txt`

Answer (score -1):

You may try `cat -e <filename>`